# Saving email attachments in Outlook that are on the server (MS Exchange)

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

I have successfully implemented the VBA code from this link to download the attachment in each email to a folder: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/saveatt.htm

However, the problem statement is now to access emails with attachments where those emails are in a folder in Outlook on the server. The message I see in the folder is the following:

*There are more items in this folder on the server*

*Click here to view more on Microsoft Exchange*

When I click to view the emails and they load in my Outlook view pane, running the code gives the following error:

**There are no messages in this folder**

I cannot change the the time period to increase the "mail to keep offline" beyond 1 month, so I wanted to know whether there is something that I can edit / update in the VBA code to run for emails on the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not in VBA - in Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), you can open the folder in the online mode and process the online items by calling `IMsgStore::OpenEntry(..., MAPI_NO_CACHE)` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/how-to-access-store-on-remote-server-in-cached-exchange-mode.

If Extended MAPI is not an option, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) - it allows to specify flags when opening a folder:

```
MAPI_NO_CACHE = &H200 
MAPI_BEST_ACCESS &H10
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set vFolder = Session.GetFolderFromID(YourOOMFolder.EntryID, , MAPI_NO_CACHE + MAPI_BEST_ACCESS)
MsgBox vFolder.Items.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. The best what you could do is to change the cache settings in the mail profile by increasing the period.

[image: cache period in the Outlook profile]

Read more about that in the [Turn on Cached Exchange Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-cached-exchange-mode-7885af08-9a60-4ec3-850a-e221c1ed0c1c#:%7E:text=Turn%20on%20or%20off%20Cached%20Exchange%20Mode&text=Click%20Account%20Settings%2C%20and%20then,then%20restart%20Microsoft%20Outlook%202010.) article.

As a possible workaround you may get access to online items in the folder if you consider using a low-level API on which Outlook was built. Or just consider using any third-party wrappers around this API such as Redemption.

EWS (or Graph API in case of Office 365) is also a possible solution, see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.